# Prove that you find number so small so that $ab < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $a$ be positive and prove that you can find some $b \geq 0$ so that $ab < 1$.

I think this is a consequence of Archimedes property:  if $x,y $ reals with $x > 0$ then we can find $n$ so that $nx > y $. Now, if put $x=1$ we have $1 > \dfrac{1}{n} y $. So if we pick $b=1/n $ then we have proved our statement. Is this a right idea?

The motivation is because I am reading complex analysis Stein books and when he proves that if $|z| < R$ then series converges, he goes like this:

Let $L=1/R$ and choose $\epsilon > 0$ so small that $(L+\epsilon) |z| = r < 1 $

Is he using the Archimedean property here?

Comment: How about $b=1/(2a)$? Or just $b=0$? :-)

Comment: $b=\frac{1}{1+a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By requiring $b\geq 0,$ it becomes trivial since you can choose $b=0$.

If $b\neq 0,$ then you can just take $b=\dfrac{1}{2a}$ or infact $b=\dfrac{1}{na}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}.$

Your idea of taking $b=\frac{1}{n}$ is correct if $n$ is chosen such that $n>a.$